# How make PyCharm automatically suggest function of a class modified by metaclass?

Tags: python, pycharm, metaclass

To simplify code dealing with the database table, I wrote a metaclass factory, like below:

```
#metaClass factory
def base_service(clz_of_model):

  @db.transactional
  def add(self, obj):
    m = clz_of_model(**obj)
    db.session.add(m)
    return m

  class BaseService(type):
     def __new__(mcs, name, base, attrs):
        attrs["add"] = add
        return super().__new__(mcs, name, base, attrs)

  return BaseService

#define a model
class UserModel(Base):
   #....

#define a service
class UserService(object,metaclass=base_service(UserModel):
   #....

#using service
user_service=UserSerivce()
user_service.add({"name":'tom'})
```

The code does work, but one inconvenience is this:

**When I am typing `user_servce.` in Pycharm, the IDE won't suggest `user_service` has a `add` function which is defined by metaclass.**

How make PyCharm's suggestion work? Could I have a better solution to using Python's metaclass?

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

Due to the simple reason that this is not statically detectable - not this, nor other tens of ways of adding dynamic methods and attributes to classes.

If pycharm depends on statically analyzing Python code to suggest auto-completion, it will never be able to go beyond the most plain, explicit code.

You class will only have the new method visible after it is created as a living Python object.

I think there are tools out there that use this approach instead (despite the rsk of triggering side effects when running imported modules) - sure, if you were coding using a Jupyter notebook, in the cells bellow you class declaration, the added methods would be visible.

I know there is a recent trend of IDEs working with embedded notebooks instead of just editing files - maybe there is a workflow that will allow you to do the developing with "living" objects, and saving all cell contents to a single .py file when you are done.

Or maybe, if your classes are in a  separate Python project than the one you are editing, pycharm itself will import the modules and be able to introspect the living class.

But above all there is one fact that remains: one should not depend on IDE's and other tools *aid* to be able to write the code they need. If the aid is available and works, all is good and well, otherwise, just write the code.

I am sorry if this sounds blunt. But what you want simply is not possible without having the dynamic-modification code actually run.

If pycharm can't do it even for files in other projects, and you want to have the dynamic methods to show up to 3rdy party users of your project when *they* are editing this, the workaround would be to have your metaclass generate Python files with the added methods - and have those modified parts as the ones that your project actually uses. You'd add a "build" step to read "template" classes in one directory, and render then to your "complete" classes in another one upon project installation. That way, even tools that depend only on static analysis of code could find it. But I think pycharm and other tools can do live introspection if the dynamic code is not in the file/project currently being edited.

Comment: there's no reason pycharm has to use static analysis, could be a flag: use imports instead of static analysis for typing